# PlotBackground color rendered differently in IE and FF

Tags: firefox, highcharts

I am creating a few charts using Highcharts.
THe plotbackground color I use is #f0f0f0.

However instead of the light gray background that I am expecting to see. In FF I notice a pinkish shade to the background. I tried using the rgb equivalent instead of #F0F0F0 but that was of no use as well.
Below is how I am setting my option.Any pointers will be really appreciated! Thanks!

```
chart: { width: 325, height: 225, marginBottom: 30, spacingBottom: 0, marginLeft: 3, marginRight: 45, spacingRight: 0, spacingBottom: 30, borderRadius: 0, marginTop: 2, type: 'area', plotBackgroundColor: '#F0F0F0' }
```

Even worse, In case of column chart, I have drawn vertical white plotlines. The effect is alternate bands of gray and pinkish shades.

Comment: The shade is a little different when we compare IE and CHrome as well. But atleast they are still gray.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this, but both for FF and Chrome works the same way: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/202/ Try to upgrade my example to reproduce that issue.

Comment: In the jsFiddle as well I can see a difference in shade in the plotbackground!

Comment: For me, background is exactly the same, sorry. Check [this screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/33/screenshot20130613at120.png/)